# ESP 01M LED circuit

Tags: led, circuit-design, esp32, pullup, rgb

I designed a small LED board using an ESP 01M. At first, the 5mm LED was working as I wanted. Sometimes the processor was reset, so I plugged a capacitor into the inputs and outputs of the AMS1117 and got a stable result, but after about 1 hour I noticed that the red color exploded.
When I looked at the value of the GPIO0 pin (normally pull-up), I read 1.9V.
What do you think could be the problem?

My circuit is as follows:

[image]

Sometimes it works but red not blinking:

https://streamable.com/0f458y

[image]

My schematic:

[image]

Application example for ESP01M:

[image]

GPIO0 ESP01M:

[image]

Comment: Could those three resistors be 33 ohm rather than 330 ohms? Your photo has high contrast that might present dark-brown *or* black.

Comment: Is the GND net actually complete? I see the AMS1117 pin 1 connected to the ESP32 pin 1 and nowhere else.

Comment: @glen_geek I checked resistors 330 ohm.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany connected to the ink GND on the plate and the GND of the power input

Comment: Very near to ground and Vcc of ESP, you should wire a 100nF SMD capacitor ...

Comment: Looking at the esp-01m datasheet, I see that GPIO12 and GPIO10 have alternate functions available.  I'm not familiar with this chip, but is there a chance that the GPIO pins are not configured properly (as MTDI and SD_DATA_3, and not as general purpose DIO)?

Comment: You must show entire system Vcc, gnd, power supply, PC cable gnd.  Many problems are caused by lack of attention to interface protection and interface cables with exposure to noise and ESD. Shielded twisted pair preferred.  Did you mean by RED color exploded it was momentarily far too bright as in over current or stuck On or Off and floating and now the interface reads 3.3 - Vf of LED = 1.9 at very low current of DVM. Does LED fail or software fail or hardware glitch? or hard fault?

Comment: @Antonio51 I plugged 100nF SMD capacitor, and I change the led, The led turned on as I wanted, and after a while, the red color did not light up, only green and blue were lit and Reseted. The things I said at the beginning happened again

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 when I change led and plug the capacitor, the red color brightened but in time very fast shined and then did not brighten again. looks like i have a hardware problem here

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75  I don't understand can you explain according to this photo? https://ibb.co/QKq8hDh

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 can you check pinout? https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/webp/introduction-to-ams1117.png.webp

Comment: Sorry I got that upside down but top cap trace is hidden

Comment: I reconnected the card to power. For a while, it worked as I wanted, as in the 1st video. then it started to react like in the 2nd video. This is actually my problem. I could not understand why.
1st video: https://streamable.com/qqvwdm
2nd video: https://streamable.com/as9vdy

Comment: code: #include <Arduino.h>

int PIN_LED_R = 12;
int PIN_LED_G = 5;
int PIN_LED_B = 10;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(PIN_LED_R, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_LED_G, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_LED_B, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(PIN_LED_R, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PIN_LED_G, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PIN_LED_B, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
  analogWrite(PIN_LED_R, 0);
  analogWrite(PIN_LED_G, 0);
  analogWrite(PIN_LED_B, 0);
  delay(500);

  analogWrite(PIN_LED_R, 128);
  analogWrite(PIN_LED_G, 128);
  analogWrite(PIN_LED_B, 255);

  delay(500);
...

Comment: esp 01m Voltage 3.0V ~ 3.6VˈTypical 3.3VˈCurrent >500mA. When I gave 3V to 3.3V from the adjustable power supply to the led circuit, GPIO0 was 2.7-2.9V and the led worked. When I gave 3.5V, I measured GPIO0 as 2.1V and the led did not work. I'm trying to find out why, any ideas?
I